Solrnet version 0.3.1 ping fail to map the response to ResponseHeader
Ping function throw:
System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'
I created ISolrHeaderResponseParser to inject in the BasicServer but the ping function does not invoke the custom implementation. I have been looking for the source code to understand that the ping function does without success.
Any hint?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
